# select different data from several tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

How could I select

```
| Customer_name | Num_of_AllTime_Orders | Num_of_different_Products_That_Customer_Ordered |
```

as a table when each data is from a different table?

I tried to count customers, join tables and group by... but no luck.

```
SELECT CompanyName, count(Customer_ID) from dbo.CUSTOMERS join dbo.ORDERS on CUSTOMERS.Customer_ID=ORDERS.CustomerID
```

Customers_Table:

```
CustomerID | Customer_Name
```

Orders_Table:

```
OrderID| Customer_ID
```

Order_Detail_Table:

```
OrderID| Product_ID |
```

I expect the output of a table which has these columns :

```
1. Customer_Name
2. Num_of_AllTime_Orders  - how many orders that costumer made?
3. Num_of_different_Products_That_Customer_Ordered - how many different products that customer ordered?
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You say your query gives you "no luck". It should give you an error message telling you exactly what to do.

Comment: @HoneyBadger , really? I don't understand why people reply when they don't want to help and just show how "smart" they are. next time just don't...

Comment: anyway, the answer is below, @GordonLinoff thanks for the help. I got it.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select CUSTOMERS.Customer_Name
    ,count(distinct ORDERS.OrderID) as Num_of_AllTime_Orders
    ,count(distinct Order_Detail_Table.Product_ID) as Num_of_different_Products_That_Customer_Ordered   
from dbo.CUSTOMERS 
    join dbo.ORDERS on CUSTOMERS.CustomerID = ORDERS.Customer_ID
    join dbo.Order_Detail_Table on ORDERS.OrderID = Order_Detail_Table.OrderID
group by CUSTOMERS.Customer_Name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Company_Name = C.CompanyName, NumOfOrders = COUNT (DISTINCT O.OrderID), NumOfProducts = COUNT (DISTINCT OD.ProductID)
FROM dbo.CUSTOMERS AS C JOIN ORDERS AS O ON C.Customer_ID=O.CustomerID JOIN ORDERDETAILS AS OD ON OD.OrderID=O.OrderID
GROUP BY C.CompanyName
ORDER BY 1
```